# "chrome://favicon/myurl" doesn't load the on the webpage but loads in new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, favicon

I am developing a personal productive app. The bookmark manager is part of it.
I use a lot of two-step verification websites so it is difficult to bypass that to get the webpage favicon.

However, when I use "chrome://favicon/https://stackoverflow.com/" I can easily get the favicon of any website.

But the issue is that it works when I open in a new tab but they don't work on my webpage however, in the

For example.

`<img src="chrome://favicon/https://stackoverflow.com/" />`

Any suggestions on how to fix it. Thanks a mill in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Get favicon by `https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico` Of any website. Just add `/favicon.ico` at the domain. There is no need of using `chrome://favicon`

Comment: I am sorry it doesn't work for all for example try this below
`https://autodesk.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Case/list?filterName=00B3g000001DhX7EAK/favicon.ico` It directly loads the website instead.

Comment: However, if I use `chrome://favicon` it works perfectly.

Comment: You can Get the icon From `https://autodesk.lightning.force.com/favicon.ico`

Comment: Can you tell Me why do you want favicons So I can suggest you accordingly.

Comment: Sure I am developing a productivity app and `bookmark manager` is part of it. When the user adds a URL it should download the favicon of that URL as well. I tried multiple methods basic websites are working fine but when I add a URL that needs a login or has two-step authentication it doesn't get the favicon of the URL.

Hope I explained clearly.

Comment: Another Solution is Provided by google. You can go to `https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=http://www.github.com` and you will get the favicon. But I don't know why this don't work for your given link.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this too it doesn't work for the websites which have two-step authentication.

Comment: I just got Something. You can go to `http://favicongrabber.com/api/grab/autodesk.lightning.force.com/` and you will get a json response and you can manipulate using JavaScript to get the favicon. I hope it will help you

Comment: It returns the Mircosoft favicon which is used for the two-step verification doesn't bypass the actual URL. 

But thank you for sharing the `favicon.ico` method. I guess will have to use the below code to strip out the domain and get the favicon.
`domain = url.split(".com/")[0]+".com/favicon.ico"` in python

Comment: Yes your code will work for websites that use .com extension. you to have to add all the domain extensions possible to make it work for all websites. If you found this helpful you can mark this as the answer. Thank you

Comment: Sure I will and I have already marked it. I appreciate your time. Thank you so much for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Often you can get icon of site by requesting `<website>/favicon.ico`. For example, it works perfectly for https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico. (and it is 32x32, not 16x16 using `chrome://favicon`).

Comment: As I mentioned it isn't working for all the sites. `https://autodesk.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Case/list?filterName=00B3g000001DhX7EAK/favicon.ico` It directly loads the website instead. 

But when I use `chrome://favicon/` it loads favicon of any site. 

And I can change the favicon size like this `chrome://favicon/size/128@1x/urlhere`